# Retro-actively add Java annotations to methods?

Tags: java, annotations, bytecode-manipulation, java-bytecode-asm

Is there a way to modify .class files in order to add Java annotations to certain methods? Basically I want to traverse methods of each class file in a jar file and annotate certain ones. Note that this is not at run-time while using the jar file. Rather, after I'm done I want to have modified class files with the annotations.

I do have access to the source code, so if there's an automatic source code modifier, that would work as well...

I'm assuming I'll need a tool such as [Javassist](http://labs.jboss.com/javassist/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). If so, which one should I use and how would I go about it?

Comment: It's certainly possible to do this by adding the proper attributes to the methods fields of the .class file.  I don't have much experience using tools to do this, though.

Comment: that's encouraging I guess...hope someone will answer soon. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling for an hour or so turned [this article](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-annotations.html) up which seems to completely answer my question: use [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). To write class files using the changed bytecode, use [ClassWriter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html).

Well, time to get to work then, I guess. :)

Answer (score 8):

Actually, this is a classic use case for AspectJ:

```
declare @method : public * BankAccount+.*(..) : @Secured(role="supervisor")
```

While I will grant you that direct byte code manipulation is more powerful, AspectJ is much more user-friendly, and it immediately gives you compiler warnings when you are doing something wrong.

Also, if you use [Load Time Weaving](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html), you can leave the original library jar unchanged, because the weaving happens at class-load time.

**Reference:**

- [Declare Annotation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-declare.html)
- [AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/) (book)